# what is the correct type for a React instance of a component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Say I have a component that takes 2 button instances:

```
export interface GridProps {
  backButton: any;
  nextButton: any;
}
```

Should the type for the button be `React.ReactNode` or `React.ReactElement`

so either:

```
export interface GridProps {
  backButton: React.ReactNode;
  nextButton: React.ReactNode;
}
```

or

```
export interface GridProps {
  backButton: React.ReactElement<any>;
  nextButton: React.ReactElement<any>;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`React.ReactNode` is more convenient way for passing markup to child components. It contains everything you can insert in JSX like `<div>{passedContent}</div>` It is used in many React component libraries. It makes sense to use `React.ReactElement<any>` only if you want to restrict customization to elements of particular class. For example `React.ReactElement<ButtonProps>`. It is useful if you want to clone passed element and append some props to it.